# Spark Profile for Projections Module Configuration Check Failed: MIN_EXECUTORS_LESS_MAX_EXECUTORS

Tags: palantir-foundry

We are on an on-prem stack. I did set up a Projection on a dataset. In the Projection configuration dialog in the build section I left the Text Box in which the Spark Profile can be set empty, as the GUI says: `The spark profiles on this projection are managed and adjusted based on data volume. Adjustments to spark profiles will only apply to the next build of this projection.`

I schedule the build to run once a day. I consistently succeeds once. From the details of the succeeded build I can see that Spark is using: dynamicAllocationMaxExecutors 40 and dynamicAllocationMinExecutors 2.

When I open the GUI of the projection again (a couple of days later), I can see that Foundry sets the following profile "NUM_EXECUTORS_1". All builds using this profile are failing. In the build details I see: `Configuration Check Failed: Min executors must be less than the max executors`

Is our Spark Profile wrong/incorrectly configured or is the Projection simply choosing a profile which is not suitable? I would like to let Foundry choose the profile based on the data volume without having to manually adjust it. Can you let me know how to best solve this issue?

Comment: thanks for raising this, sounds like a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Spark Profiles documentation](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/optimizing-pipelines/spark-profiles-reference/#profile-table), when setting `NUM_EXECUTORS_1` this adds the following spark configuration `spark.executor.instances: 1; spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors: 1`. Your stack has the following Spark configuration set as default `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors: 2`, therefore a pre-launch check `MIN_EXECUTORS_LESS_MAX_EXECUTORS` fails, since the `minExecutors` is greater than `maxExecutors`.

I raised this with the product team, asked whether `NUM_EXECUTORS_1` could set `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` as well. Other option would be to change the stack default to `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors: 1`. Thank you for reporting this.

Answer (score 0):

Our onside support team let me know that we have configured a minimum of 2 executors on our stack.

If Foundry then tries to use the profile NUM_EXECUTORS_1 the max value of this profile is below the configured minimum of 2.

Expected behavior of Foundry would be, that the dynamic selection of the Spark Profile honors the configured minimum thresholds. So yes, I would consider this a bug.